# How to install Paltalk Messenger?

Tags: yahoo

I tried to install paltalk messenger in Playonlinux app, it got installed but showed an error :/

is there a way to install Paltalk messenger in ubuntu?

Comment: What is the *exact* error message?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with wine but since PlaxOnLinux is just tweaked wine then I think you won't make it work. You can access paltalk with this: http://express.paltalk.com/

Comment: yea i checked that, in browser its able to work but in browser there are certain features which dont work like for ex using mic, which only works in application. But i was thinking if there is a way to run the actual application in ubuntu.

Comment: then there is no other way for using paltalk except using wine. You should try with different versions of wine because in my expirience, some win apps don't work in one version but work in other version of wine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Wine application From "Ubuntu Software Center"
2. Download The EXE File From paltalk.com
3. Open The EXE Paltalk and run it
   its will work